# Does having a child has a negative/positive impact in karma?

Tags: karma, parents

The question aims towards to creating a new life and not to the desire from which said life is concived. Other way of this question would be: the act of giving a life which can be seen as a being with it's own karma, creates more karma to one self?
 Has the buddha ever talked about this?

Comment: Hello wanderer and welcome to Buddhism.SE. We've put together some information to help you get started [here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?)

Comment: Thank you very much, i have read that but please inform me if i infringe in some way any rule while im getting to know the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the *intention* behind the action. If the intention is unwholesome then it will lead to unwhole resultants and vice versa if its wholesome. It is the intention that has kammic potency.

[Here is a quote from the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C4%81hula) about what the Buddha said when he was about to leave his palace and at the same time got news about his newborn son:

> *"Prince Siddhartha was preparing himself to leave the palace. One account claims that when he received the news of his son's birth he replied Rāhu jāto, bandhanam jātam — "A rāhu is born, a fetter has arisen." Accordingly the child was named Rāhula, meaning "fetter", or "impediment", recognizing that the child could be a tie that bound him to his wife Yashodhara, a binding that may impede a search for enlightenment. Others, however, feel rāhu does not mean "fetter" in this sense. The second account, found in the Mūlasarvāstivāda vinaya, is that Rāhula received his name in accordance with an eclipse of the moon, caused by the snake Rahu. In Japanese he is called Ragora (羅睺羅).*
>
> *Supporting the first account, in the Dhammapada, the pleasure and joy that a man receives in his wife and children is called a "soft fetter" that ties individuals to life and suffering, not just through eventual loss and separation of loved ones but more deeply and subtly may act as ties to cyclic existence (samsara)".*

Answer (score 2):

Having a child is a long term commitment, responsibility and attachment which comes part and parcel. Also raising a child can be a opportunity to do good as well in raising children the right way.  (Putta darasa sangaho. “cherishing of wife and children”- [Mangala Sutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangala_Sutta)) This attachment can perhaps in the long run result in generation negative karma, while the positive aspects can lead to positive karma. It is up to you to balance the two, hence this aspect of Karma you accumulate more.

Answer (score 1):

Initially Yes, but caring for them in the proper way negates and eventually swings into positive.

Answer (score 0):

According to Buddhism, having a child involves three conditions a fertile female egg, male sperm, and a being to be born, that is, the transmigrant/samsaric consciousness (vijnana + in two parts knowing). During unprotected sex the transmigrant will latch on to the embryo who picks out the gender. When you know this I hope you will be much wiser.